# How to find session variable present or not

Tags: jsp, servlets

How I can find values is set to variable in session or not?

```
if(session.getAttribute("tot_demand"))//need to change

  //if value is already set then do this.

else

  //if not set then do this.
```

What do I need to write, for the above code to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compare to `null`:

```
if (session.getAttribute("tot_demand") != null) {
   // already set
} else {
   // not yet set
}
```